# Getting error: Method not found: 'Void RestSharp.RestClient.set_BaseUrl(System.String)'. in Twilio-CSharp

Tags: c#, dependencies, twilio, restsharp, nopcommerce

I am using MVC5 Application And implement twilio rest api for send sms but I am getting error on :

```
 var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
```

My restsharp dll version is 105.0.1 and also I have older 104.4.0
and I was try twilio latest version and older both but seems getting error.

> An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in
>   Nop.Plugin.SMSProvider.nopSMS.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Method not found: 'Void
>   RestSharp.RestClient.set_BaseUrl(System.String)'.

What should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

RestSharp made a breaking change in their last release, changing the BaseUrl property from a string to a System.Uri type.  The [Twilio library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/csharp/install) was updated to address this change and a new package was released.

If you install Twilio package 3.6.25 then it should install RestSharp 105.0.1 as a dependency.

Hope that helps.